# Why is "do" needed in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

Why is DO needed in the sentence below? (would it read well without it?)

*Although thunder and lightning are produced at the same time, light waves travel faster than sound waves **do**, so we see the lightning before we hear the thunder.*

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's not needed.  *Than* can take different kinds of complements:

1. > **Light waves** travel faster than **sound waves**.

   Here, the noun phrases *light waves* and *sound waves* are compared.
2. > **Light waves travel** faster than **sound waves travel**.

   Here, the clauses *light waves travel* and *sound waves travel* are compared.
3. > **Light waves travel** faster than **sound waves do**.

   This is the same as example 2, except that the verb *travel* has been replaced with the pro-verb *do* to avoid repetition.

All three of these examples are perfectly grammatical and have the same meaning.

---

Historical note:

Some observers would explain example 1 via ellipsis, claiming that *do* is ellipted:

> **Light waves** travel faster than **sound waves** <s>do</s>.

This is not correct as a description, but the analysis has been around for some time, dating back to the prescriptive grammarian Robert Lowth in the 18th century, who claimed that *than* was always a conjunction and never a preposition.  We can see this is false because *than me* is perfectly grammatical, and has been in common use since before Lowth made his analysis.

Lowth's claim was that it should instead be *than I*, while Joseph Priestly claimed the opposite, that it should always be *than me*, and grammarians argued fiercely over the topic.  However, both were shown to be descriptively incorrect by their contemporary William Ward, who noted in 1765 that *than* was commonly used both as a preposition and as a conjunction.

For more information about this point of grammatical contention, I recommend the entry for *than* in *Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of English Usage*, which can be found on pages 892–893.

Comment: There is speech and there is writing, and they are quite different. In fact, spoken language has its own grammar. Than me is fine in some contexts but not others. Imagine a  presidential speech or a speech by a British PM. I think "than I am"" would be preferred (not including the orange man).

Comment: @Lambie http://www.ukpol.co.uk/david-cameron-2016-speech-with-president-obama/: "Below is the text of the speech made by David Cameron at the Foreign and Commonwealth Office in London on 22 April 2016. [...] Let me be clear. When it comes to the special relationship between our two countries, there’s no greater enthusiast **than me**." So... nope, you're wrong. I agree that *than I am* is more formal-sounding than *than me*, but obviously *than me* isn't markedly informal as you seem to imply.

Answer (score 0):

In formal comparative utterances,  auxiliary verbs are often repeated:

- You speak **faster than I** **do**.
- He jumps **higher than John does**.
- We like chocolate **more than our families do**.
- Light waves **travel fasterer than sound waves do.**

In everyday conversation, the less formal is:

- You speak faster than him. [notice him instead of he does]
- We like chocolate more than them. [notice them  instead of they do]
- I like this exercise more than him. [notice him instead of he does]

Please note: Some people do use the more formal comparative forms. The informal one is not acceptable in formal writing. Your piece is formal writing.

And that's the pattern for formal comparatives versus colloquial usage.

Comment: Although I see that the Urban Dictionary recognises **fasterer**, I somehow think that a redundant **er** crept into your light wave travels.